# How do I make it so the "app" property on <v-navigation-drawer> doesn't apply on 'xs' screen sizes so the drawer is over top of the content?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `<v-navigation-drawer>` and I have it working almost like I want. The problem is I want the `app` prop to be false on 'xs' screens so the navigation drawer is over top of the content :

**app property**

> [Designates the component as part of the application layout. Used for dynamically adjusting content sizing. Components using this prop should reside outside of v-main component to function properly. You can more information about layouts on the application page. Note: this prop automatically applies position: fixed to the layout element. You can overwrite this functionality by using the absolute prop](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-navigation-drawer/#props)

Basically what I want to do is remove the `app` prop for `xs` screens, or figure out how to make make ` over the card in this example:

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/eYdeZBV?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a conditional and fixed property to `<v-navigation-drawer :app="drawer" fixed>`